# call a JQuery function from code behind in C#

Tags: javascript, jquery, c#-4.0, code-behind

I want to call this JQuery function from C# code behind but it is not work
Here is the JQuery function

```
function showDialog(id, title) {
$(id).dialog({
    modal: true, minWidth: 600, title: title
});
$(id).parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
```

}

and here is the code behind which i use

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "myfunction", "$(document).ready(function(){showDialog('#editCustomer','نحديث معلومات عميل');});", true);
```

But it is not work

Comment: to register clientscript, you need either scriptmanager or ajax toolkit script manager....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "myfunction", "<script type='text/javascript'>myFunction(params...);</script>", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page,this.GetType(), "myfunction", "$(document).ready(function(){showDialog('#editCustomer','نحديث معلومات عميل');});", true);
```

also try first putting your jQuery function inside $().