# Call jquery button click event from code behind

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am using the below code to display a div on button click event. Is there any way to call this button click event from C# code behind.

```
 $(document).on("click", '#AddNew', function (e) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    if ($NewEntry.is(":hidden")) {
                        $NewEntry.slideDown("slow", "easeOutBounce");
                        $NewEntry.slideDown("slow", "easeOutBounce");
                        $filter.slideUp("slow");
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        $NewEntry.slideUp("slow");
                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

Comment: C# is server side programming. JQuery is client side programming. So, my guess is a no!

Comment: You mean you want to call this event from serverside callback?

Comment: @Sid i need to open the popup from code behind.

Comment: you cannot, you need to understand difference between client side and server side

Comment: @user3710059 change your question then and dont post only jquery code, add code that you used for calling your code behind

Comment: possible duplicate of [call a JQuery function from code behind in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19020303/call-a-jquery-function-from-code-behind-in-c-sharp)

Comment: have been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19020303/call-a-jquery-function-from-code-behind-in-c-sharp) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19111890/calling-jquery-function-using-c-sharp-codebehind-with-return-value)

Comment: why are you using `.on` are the controls loaded from jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

use this code :

```
protected void myButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "tmp", "<script type='text/javascript'>myFunction(params...);</script>", false);
}
```

more read : [Call jQuery function from ASP.NET code behind C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397165/call-jquery-function-from-asp-net-code-behind-c-sharp)